# Comparison of basic strength of benzylamine and ammonia

Tags: organic-chemistry, amines

According to me, ammonia should be the stronger base for two reasons:

1. $\ce{-C_6H_5}$ group shows $-I$ effect, due to which electron density on $\ce{N}$ atom of benzylamine decreases
2. steric hindrance in benzylamine is more than that in ammonia

But their $\mathrm{pK_b}$ values are: benzylamine: $4.70$ and ammonia : $4.75$. High $\mathrm{pK_b}$ value of ammonia shows that it is *actually **less*** basic than benzylamine, contrary to my reasoning. Why is it so?

Comment: See nitrogen inversion $\ce{->}$[Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nitrogen_inversion)

Comment: Due to ring inversion tendency in NH3, IT IS lesser basic wrt benzylamine. The ring inversion tendency is lesser, in benzylamine

Comment: Adding methyl amine pKb = 3.4 into the discussion might help to see what a phenyl group can do. Why quibble over a 0.05 difference in pKb when there is a whole factor of ten to worry about.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Everything you said is correct, except that it is more relevant to consider the inductive effect of methyl on nitrogen: electron density is donated to nitrogen.

The inductive effect of phenyl is on the methyl, decreasing its ability to donate electron density to nitrogen, but apparently not completely.

I suppose that if you increased the negative inductive effect of the phenyl group with a couple of nitro groups, the basicity of the compound would decrease.

Answer (score 0):

Benzylamine is $\ce{C6H5CH2NH2}.$ Therefore, $\ce{NH2}$ group is bonded to $\ce{C6H5-CH2}$ unit which has greater +*I* effect. Therefore, it increases electron density on $\ce{N}$ and makes benzylamine more basic.